# Load colors into comboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, colors, text-editor

I am making a homemade text editor and in it trying to make a control used to change the color of the text, on my tool bar I have a combo box in which I want to be able to load system colors into so that the user may change the color of the selected text. I can not figure out how to populate the combo box with these colors, I have tried variation of things I have found on the internet within my page_loaded event, but can not seem to get it to work. Hope you can help

Thanks Beef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code to populate a combo box with list of all colors

Declare a resource

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
         <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,            Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
 </ObjectDataProvider>

<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"    MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Then use that resource in combo box like this

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

In order to use `sys:string` you will have to include 
`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: thanks, but where about in the xaml code do I declare the resource? right now I have it inside my <ToolBarTray> tag but am getting an error trying to use the type <sys:String>

Comment: see updated answer. Add a tag  `<Window.Resources>  declare resource here <Window.Resources/>` inside the `Window` and declare resource inside it

Comment: thanks, i got it working now, do you know if there is a way i can get the actual color to show up beside its corrosponding name