# Is there a premade color palette in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, color-palette

I am currently creating a basic text editor that has basic functions such as changing fonts and sizes.

I am currently trying to add color changing capibilities and I was wondering if there was any premade color pallettes already in the default libraries. I have looked around and have found that i can download premade palettes but i want to just stick to the default stuff.

If theres not a way my backup plan is just to load colour names into a combo box.

Also I am coding using .WPF and adding my items through the XAML with methods in C# classes.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a premade color palette for wpf?

Comment: Ok.  Then please edit your question title/body to make that explicit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'palette' suggests two things: a control to select and/or mix a color or a collection of colors that go together nicely.

For the first: http://www.google.nl/search?q=wpf+color+picker there a lots to pick from.

For matching colors have a look at http://kuler.adobe.com/ it allows you to create a set or copy an existing matching set of colors.

Answer (score 1):

There is `System.Windows.Media.Colors` which is a set of well known colors.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834221/load-colors-into-combobox/6834497#6834497) for an example of how to load those into a combobox:

Comment: Yea thats what i was looking at for the combo box idea. I was thinking that it would look nicer with a palette but that seems to do the job if there isnt a way